# Roundcube webmail(or any other) integration to python-django app

Tags: python, django, webmail, roundcube

I am building a backend,which is having an email section.But i dont get any proper guides to configure webmail on my django app.

Does anybody know how to integrate roundcube or any webmail to the django webapp...

I have been searching on web for samples..but i didn't get one yet..

Comment: what did you end up doing?